# training time duration in bixby

Tags: duration, bixby

I am building a sample capsule where i will add user activity data. The sample utterance would be "I walked for 2 hr and completed 2 km distance". The training source code is as follow

```
[g:AddExerciseResultConcept] i (walked)[v:ExerciseType:Walking] for (2 hr)[v:time.DateTimeExpression] and completed (2 km)[v:measurement.Length]
```

IDE showing it as a **illegal plan**.

[image]

My **action model** is like

```
action (AddExercise) {
       description (adding exercise value)
       type (Search)
       collect {
         input (duration) {
         type (time.DurationPeriod)
         min (Required) max (One)
       }    
       input (distance) {
         type (measurement.Length)
         min (Optional) 
       }
       input (exerciseType) {
         type (ExerciseType)
         min (Required) max (One)
       }
      }
      output (AddExerciseResultConcept)
}
```

The **AddExerciseResultConcept** is of type text.
What mistake did i make here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you submitting the capsule through support ticket.

After reviewing the capsule, I would recommend these 2 fixes:

1. disable training of similar utterance but different goal.
2. use viv.time.DurationPeriod as tagged input and action input type.

In this screenshot, I've added a training example with minutes. Please also note I've disable the last training as it is similar utterance with a different action that could cause confusion. 
[image]

After compile, as the debugger shows the content of `duration` in JS, developer can easily get `duration.periodHours` and `duration.periodMinutes` as integers. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will definite do that. on query from me, does the conflict happen for utterance with similar goal or it can happen with utterances of different goal? In my case I only have single utterance for the **AddExerciseResultConcept** goal.

Comment: To me it usually with a similar utterance with a different goal. It is a conflict that when present such utterance as NL, Bixby planner cannot decide which action. But I would say same gaol conflict is possible because of the the tagged input may result confusion as well. We will learn more about your case once we have your full capsule for review.